# Get data from Streamlit in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I was wondering if it is possible to load data from a f.e. a pandas dataframe or an Excel file into a Snowflake table via the "Streamlit in Snowflake" application.

Is this functionality supported or is it better to use an alternative route?

The reason for my question is the following link which indicates that the "streamlit.file_uploader" functionality is absent at this stage of "streamlit in snowflake":
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/streamlit/limitations

Comment: Yes - you can use Streamlit to load data into a table, as long as you can get the data into Streamlit in the first place. So if this data is in a Snowflake table you can read it, transform it and then write it back to back to a SF table. If this data is external to Streamlit/SF then you can only use it if there's a method available to read it

Comment: And that's exactly my question. Is there a method available in "streamlit in snowflake" to read data that is external to Streamlit and Snowflake?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is equivalent method to "streamlit.file_uploader" available. There are ways of reading data external to Snowflake/Streamlit but they are specific to the type of file and its type of location. For example, if the data is accessible via an API then you can access it in Streamlit

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read up on that? I was under the impression that streamlit in snowflake didn't have that functionality at all.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/streamlit/limitations#you-cannot-access-an-external-api

Comment: Could be me, but I don't see how I could load a csv or Excel file in particular to the streamlit in SF environment.

Comment: Apologies, I realise I missed the rather important word "not" from my second to last comment. It should have said "As far as I'm aware, there is not an equivalent method to "streamlit.file_uploader" available"